# SQL Server - Return full record for Duplicated Field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Suppose I have a SQL Server table with many columns something along the lines of:

```
Col1:    Col2:    Col3:   ...   Coln:
Val1_1   Val1_2   Val1_3        Val1_n
Val2_1   Val2_2   Val2_3        Val2_n
Val3_1   Val3_2   Val3_3        Val3_n
Val3_1   Val4_2   Val4_3        Val4_n
Val3_1   Val5_2   Val5_3        Val5_n
```

In this case, `Val3_1` is repeated in `Col1` for the last 3 records, whereas the remaining values are not repeated.

How can I write a query to return the full set of columns where `Col1`'s value is duplicated to get back:

```
Col1:    Col2:    Col3:   ...   Coln:
Val3_1   Val3_2   Val3_3        Val3_n
Val3_1   Val4_2   Val4_3        Val4_n
Val3_1   Val5_2   Val5_3        Val5_n
```

I tried using the `Group By` function, but I had to write out each column's name (which gets very frustrating), I was hoping for something along the lines of:

```
SELECT MyTable.* FROM MyTable WHERE count(MyTable.Col1) OVER() > 1
```

Obviously, this didn't work, but how could I do something along those lines??

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a subquery:

```
select *
from mytable t1
inner join
(
  select count(col1) Total, col1
  from mytable
  group by col1
  having count(col1) > 1
) t2
  on t1.col1 = t2.col1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87fc3/2)

Or you can use `count(*) over()`:

```
select *
from
(
  select *,
    count(*) over(partition by col1) tot
  from mytable
) src
where tot > 1
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/87fc3/5)

Comment: ABSOLUTELY PERFECT!!!!! Thank you!!! - Waiting on time to pass to mark your solution. THANK YOU!!!!